# "Garbage" values in 2D array when trying to print via function

Tags: c++, arrays, function, multidimensional-array

I'm making a classic tic-tac-toe type game but with the board size defined by the user.

When trying to print the board (with asterisks representing open spaces) after the user specifies a size for the board, I'm only getting what seem to be garbage values.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

const int BOARD_MAX = 10;
const int BOARD_MIN = 3;

bool sizecheck(int);
void displayBoard(char [][BOARD_MAX], int);

int main(void)
{
    int boardsize, i, j;
    char grid[BOARD_MAX][BOARD_MAX];

    cout << "Please enter the size of the board (" << BOARD_MIN << " - " << BOARD_MAX << "): ";
    cin >> boardsize;

    if ((sizecheck(boardsize)) == false)
    {
        do
        {
            cout << "Must be a number between " << BOARD_MIN << " and " << BOARD_MAX << ". Try again." << endl;
            cout << "Please enter the size of the board (" << BOARD_MIN << " - " << BOARD_MAX << "): ";
            cin >> boardsize;

            sizecheck(boardsize);
        }

        while ((sizecheck(boardsize)) == false);
    }

    for (i = 0; i < boardsize; i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; i < boardsize; i++)
        {
            grid[i][j] = '*';
        }
    }

    displayBoard(grid, boardsize);

    return 0;
}

bool sizecheck(int fboardsize)
{
    if ((fboardsize > BOARD_MAX) || (fboardsize < BOARD_MIN))
    {
        return false;
    }

    else
    {
        return true;
    }
}


void displayBoard(char fgrid[][BOARD_MAX], int fboardsize)
{
    int i, j;

    for (i = 0; i < (fboardsize); i++)
    {
        for (j = 0; j < (fboardsize); j++)
        {
            cout << fgrid[i][j];
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Output:

[out http://puu.sh/6IfHU.png](http://puu.sh/6IfHU.png)

The program is obviously a work in progress; I'm just having trouble with the printing of the array after using a function. If i try to print without the function, it works fine. I'm having a hard time figuring out what's going wrong.

Sorry for the super basic question; I'm very new to C++ and programming in general and am quite stumped.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check you grid init cycle...

```
for (i = 0; i < boardsize; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; i < boardsize; i++)
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, and sorry for wasting your time! It slipped my notice at least 45 times. :)

Comment: happens :) take a look at c++ and stuff like for_each, it helps to reduce potential mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

There is a typo in your code where you initialize the board: It should read

```
for (i = 0; i < boardsize; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < boardsize; j++)
    {
        grid[i][j] = '*';
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh lord, I feel silly! I guess sometimes it takes someone else to look at your code to point out dumb mistakes. Thanks!